# Tomcat: Cannot serialize session into database

Tags: java, session, tomcat, struts2, tomcat7

We are using Tomcat 7 session persistence into MySQL.

We frequently get this error and stack trace. As per these threads, this error was a bug in struts which already has been resolved.

[Struts2 portlet NotSerializable exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10806320/struts2-portlet-notserializable-exception)

We are using Struts 2.3.16 and still getting this error. Any ideas ?

```
WARNING: Cannot serialize session attribute org.apache.struts2.util.InvocationSessionStore.invocationMap for session DA0863E5D8B4FD7DBC19B9C3D520D4DB
java.io.NotSerializableException: com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$ConstructorInjector
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1183)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.util.ReferenceMap.writeObject(ReferenceMap.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1267.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:988)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1495)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347)
    at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1129)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor234.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:988)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1495)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.writeObject(StandardSession.java:1671)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.writeObjectData(StandardSession.java:1077)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.JDBCStore.save(JDBCStore.java:824)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.PersistentManagerBase.writeSession(PersistentManagerBase.java:834)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.PersistentManagerBase.processMaxIdleBackups(PersistentManagerBase.java:1040)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.PersistentManagerBase.processPersistenceChecks(PersistentManagerBase.java:464)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.PersistentManagerBase.processExpires(PersistentManagerBase.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.ManagerBase.backgroundProcess(ManagerBase.java:519)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1352)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1530)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1519)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What causes a NotSerializableException in Tomcat 7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6893833/what-causes-a-notserializableexception-in-tomcat-7)

Comment: Looks like you put something in the session that has reference to Container or that https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-3838

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> WARNING: Cannot serialize session attribute ABC for session XYZ

You have probably included in your session an object not implementing the `Serializable` interface.